# SQLite DB security iOS XCode DataProtection FileProtection

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, data-protection

I am implementing the security for SQLite- DB on iOS, meaning that the DB is encrypted, so that just my app can read it. 
I have applied the DataProtection in the XCode and set the FileProtection-attribute for the DB-file to FileProtectionType.complete.
But, when I connect with my MacBook to my iPhone, I can easily get the DB and read it with some external app. 
What am I missing? 
Is this DataProtection- feature and FileProtection- attribute meant for something else?

Comment: SQLite doesn't support encryption unless you are willing to pay.  Realm supports encyrption.  https://www.sqlite.org/see/doc/trunk/www/readme.wiki

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I also found that. But, what is the purpose of DataProtection and FileProtection in XCode?

Comment: I has nothing to do with apps created by your or me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sql cipher` for your db protection .

Refer link 
[SQL Cipher in ios](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/ios-tutorial/)